# WPFToolkit:Split button dropdown button disable button

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

[image]

I am using WPF split button  which is inherited from

```
xmlns:extToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit/extended"
```

The issue is I want to disable  , the button ' the one below(Right side of Button 'Conf' in below 'downarrow present in the below fig) , If user clicks on Left side of the button the rightside should be disabled and the button(leftside) background should change to yellow.please find below the xaml , I am using the wpf split button , dropdown content in this case .please let me know if you have any idea

```
<extToolkit:SplitButton x:Name="ABCbutton"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Command="{Binding ACommand}"
                        FontSize="16> 
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=AButton}"
               Text="A"/>
    <extToolkit:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Command="{Binding BCommand}"
                    Padding="3"
                    Style="{DynamicResource   
                    DropDownButtonMenuButton}">
                <TextBlock Margin="0,3,6,3" 
                           Text="B"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding BCommand}"
                    Padding="3"
                    Style="{DynamicResource 
                    DropDownButtonMenuButton}">
                <TextBlock Margin="0,3,6,3"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           Text="C"/>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </extToolkit:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
</extToolkit:SplitButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this, you will likely be better off creating your own control.  The split button can't really handle what you are talking about without a good deal of modification.

Essentially your new control will consist of two buttons, visually styled so that they look like they blend together.  Each will have it's own background and enabled property.  Add a ViewModel to help control behaviors and set properties, and I think you would be in business.  Keep in mind that all of the controls that are supplied in any of the toolkits, frameworks, control packs, etc are made with the primitive types of drawing and framework elements (line, rectangle, border, content presenter, panel, etc) with specialized behavior code.

I end up making a lot of custom controls just because there is not one that perfectly replicates what I want.

Comment: Hi,

I also had a new requirement like   , When ever the Right side of split button is clicked , The Left side  should toggle i.e work  as a button 


previously ,it has a dropdown content (Like Below Arrow symbol),Now it should have a  single 

button in place of dropdown content with 'X' symbol.please let me know how can we acheive it.